# IHostedService StartAsync called randomely and causes Wrong Timer intervals

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm using `IHostedService` back since Asp.net core version 2.1.
I noticed in my logs that **StartAsync** is called sometimes alot in very messy intervals from 8 mins to one hour and that calls my **DoWorkAsync** each time.
I have a long process that I don't want it to be recalled on those small intervals It runs in a timer each two hours in normal cases using **Timer**.

```
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Background Service is starting.");
        _timer = new Timer(DoWorkAsync, null, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2),
            TimeSpan.FromHours(2));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

I'm considering using lock statement but if I made the lock on private object would it be there to lock execution when **StartAsync** called again.
I'm concerned because the process calls WSI (Webservice) on another server , and afraid it might be recalled before previous call answered and make the other server crashed.
My logging is simply a text file that log times in **StartAsync** and **DoWorkAsync**.
I'm running this on Aws windows instance. If the problem might be crashes or self restart how would I see the causes of it. I don't think my simple text file would catch it.

Comment: `IHostedService.StartAsync()` is called once per application lifetime. Does your application crash a lot?

Comment: no, the WSI of the other system crash

Comment: I'm not talking about the "WSI" (what does that mean?), I'm talking about your ASP.NET Core host. `StartAsync()` is called once. Please consider editing your question with interpunction (not dashes) and adding additional details such as relevant logs.

Comment: you should write some logs for the event of *starting the app*. Then you should see that your app somehow restarts frequently, making your hosted service start in the same rhythm.

Comment: If your `StartAsync` method is being called more than once, then you have bigger problems than whatever your question is asking about. And why are you mentioning `ExecuteAsync`? You said `IHostedService`, not `BackgroundService`. Your code isn't telling the whole story.

Comment: About ExecuteAsync you are true. Because it was attempt back at this time to implement not existing **BackgroundService** so this **ExecuteAsync** would be **DoWorkAsync**.

Comment: My Logs are simple text file which I put some lines into it when I'm in **StartAsync** so it's not really useful. And if my problem that application restarts or crashes randomly. Despite the fact it has been running on AWS 2 years now I still would ask how can I catch the problem that crashes it? Especially that I detect that **StartAsync** runs frequently maybe half an hour between each run.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the `StartAsync()` is not supposed to hold a callback object and probably cause your troubles. Pls consider this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/timer-service. It does, what you want to do, but in the right manner.